# how to write a subquery using split_str

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query and I used SPLIT_STR for one of my field

```
SELECT id, approved_studied, 
       SPLIT_STR(approved_studied, '||', 8) as dissertation 
       SPLIT_STR(approved_studied, '||', 7) as university
FROM temp_users
```

Now I want to filter

> WHERE dissertation LIKE '%Planting%' OR university LIKE '%Oxford%'

How to write this subquery? This is what I have come up with so far:

```
SELECT P1.approved_studied, P1.dissertation
FROM P1 
WHERE P1.dissertation LIKE '%Planting%' OR university LIKE '%Oxford%' (
     SELECT id, approved_studied, 
            SPLIT_STR(approved_studied, '||', 8) as dissertation 
            SPLIT_STR(approved_studied, '||', 7) as university
     FROM temp_users AS P1
)
```

This is very Old data and coding :( I have tried to create sql fiddle but it didn't let me proceed. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bca40/7

Comment: I thought so. You've got to move the definition of your stored function SPLIT_STR to the schema panel (left side) of the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need subquery here, just add the where condition:

```
SELECT id, approved_studied, 
       SPLIT_STR(approved_studied, '||', 8) as dissertation,
       SPLIT_STR(approved_studied, '||', 7) as university  
FROM temp_users
WHERE SPLIT_STR(approved_studied, '||', 8) LIKE '%Planting%' AND 
      SPLIT_STR(approved_studied, '||', 7) LIKE '%oxford%'
```

Note you can't use alias name in the where condition.

*The string operation won't run twice.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have other field also to search e.g.  SPLIT_STR(approved_studied, '||', 7) as university. Is there any way to imelement this? - just updated my answer

Comment: @IsaacRajaei You see by yourself that it's no good idea to store multiple delimiter separeted values in one column.

Comment: I know. bu Unfortunately this is an old code and I have to some how manage that. There are thousents of fields that has been stored so far :(

Comment: Thank you. I think it can't be better than this.